# Why is these error? DeprecationWarning

Tags: 21.10, nodejs

(node:44809) [LRU_CACHE_OPTION_maxAge] DeprecationWarning: The maxAge option is deprecated. please use options.ttl instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
sh: 1: create-react-app: Permission denied

Comment: Both are self-explanatory - DeprecationWarning means that `maxAge` is being deprecated and it lists what to use instead. `sh: 1: create-react-app: Permission denied` means that permission was denied. Running that command again with `sudo` may fix it.

Comment: warnings are NOT errors.